# Why does first use of \gls look different than \glsfirst?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I customized the layout of acronyms which works well for \gls. 
Surprisingly it does not work when using \glsfirst.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
    acronym,
]{glossaries} 

\renewcommand*{\SetCustomDisplayStyle}[1]{%
    % need only to redefine the use of displayfirst 
    \defglsdisplayfirst[acronym]{%
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{glsacrfootnote}}%
        {% footnote style
            \glsentryshort{\glslabel}\protect\footnote{%
                \glsentryshort{\glslabel}: \glsentrylong{\glslabel}%
            }
        }
        {% inline style
            \glsentryshort{\glslabel} (\glsentrylong{\glslabel})%
        }%
    }%
}

\SetCustomStyle

\newacronym{UML}{UML}{Unified Modeling Language}

\begin{document}
\gls{UML}\\
\gls{UML}\\
\glsfirst{UML}\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\glsfirst` uses "long form (LF)" by default.

Comment: How can I make both behave the same? I was expecting the internal logic to be something along:  
`\gls{  
    \if\first#1  
        \glsfirst{#1}  
    \else  
        \glsother{#1}  
    \fi  
}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\glsfirst` uses the value of the`first` key. The custom style sets this by default to `\acrfullformat{long}{short}`, which in turn defaults to `long (short)`. You haven't overridden this behaviour (which can be done by redefining `\CustomAcronymFields` or `\acrfullformat`).

`\gls` uses `\glsdisplayfirst{first}{description}{symbol}{insert}` on first use and `\glsdisplay{text}{description}{symbol}{insert}` on subsequent use, where `first` is the value of the `first` key (or `firstplural` for `\glspl`) and `text` is the value of the `text` key (or `plural` for `\glspl`). You've redefined `\glsdisplayfirst` so that it ignores its arguments, so it doesn't actually use the value of the `first` key, which is why `\gls` on first use doesn't produce the same thing as `\glsfirst`. Note that since you're ignoring all the arguments, including the fourth one `insert`, if you try to use the final optional argument of `\gls`, it will have no effect.

It's better to just redefine `\acrfullformat`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
    acronym,
]{glossaries} 

\ifglsacrfootnote
 \renewcommand{\acrfullformat}[2]{%
   #2\protect\footnote{#2: #1}%
 }
\else
 \renewcommand{\acrfullformat}[2]{#2\space(#1)}
\fi

\SetCustomStyle

\newacronym{UML}{UML}{Unified Modeling Language}

\begin{document}
\gls{UML}

\gls{UML}

\glsfirst{UML}

\acrfull{UML}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of result]

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!